# What's wrong with this code? I think I messed up in the communication between HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a total newbie to programming.  I've been doing exercises on Codecademy for JavaScript for a little while, but there's obviously huge amounts I still don't know/understand.  I've written a few things in those exercises, but nothing that anyone has or would actually use.  I was planning on keeping it that way for a little longer, but today at work a chance came up to do a little thing and I wanted to challenge myself so I decided to try it.

The idea is to create a form where people can enter their basic information and have it set them a daily calorie amount that conforms to their weight loss goals.  It's based around the Basal Metabolic Rate, the Harris Benedict Equation, and a little twist to fit my company's particular program.

I was able to find the Javascript on Dreamingincode for a basic BMR calculator which I then modified to make the adjustments we need.  Somewhere in that process, something has gone wrong.  When I save the file as a .html file and then open it in the browser, the form appears and you can fill everything out, but when you click the button, it just refreshes the screen.

I know this is stupid to all of you that actually know what you're doing, but I really want to make this work.  If any of you feel like being heroic, please look at what I have and tell me where I screwed up.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Daily Calorie Goal</title>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Calculate() {

    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var goal = document.getElementById("goal").value;

    if(gender=="male") 
        {
            val1 = 6.23 * weight;
            val2 = 12.7 * height;
            val3 = 6.8 * age;
            dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

            result = 66 + val1 + val2 - val3;

            cals = result * 1.55;
            calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;

        }
    else if (gender=="female")
        {
            val1 = 6.23 * weight;
            val2 = 4.7 * height;
            val3 = 4.7 * age;
            dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

            result = 655 + val1 + val2 - val3;

            cals = result * 1.55;
            calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;
        }



    document.write ('This is your Daily Calorie Goal. To achieve your goal, just consume fewer than this number of calories every day:<b>   ' + calMax.toFixed(2) + '</b><br>');

}



</script>

<form action="#">
    Gender  : <select id="gender"><option value="male">Male</option><option value="female">Female</option></select><br />
    Weight (lbs.)   : <input type="text" id="weight" /><br />
    Height (inches): <input type="text" id="height" /><br />
    Age     : <input type="text" id="age" /><br />
    Goal    : <select id="Goal"><option value=5>Lose 5 Pounds</option><option value=10>Lose 10 Pounds</option><option value=15>Lose 15 Pounds</option><option value=20>Lose 20 Pounds</option><option value=25>Lose 25 Pounds</option></select><br />


    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Get My Daily Calorie Goal" onclick="Calculate()" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: fyi: you're missing a `</body>`.

Comment: also, JS is case sensitive. Your id is `Goal` but you're selecting `goal`

Comment: @Roddy: It is probably missing, but FWIW, the end tag (and start tag actually) is optional.

Comment: Just pointing it out. The OP indicates he's new to scripting.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas You're right to point it out. I shouldn't put it on one end if I'm not going to put it on the other. Either way may be fine, but half and half is a bad habit to get into. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

You had one of your ids (Goal) spelled with a capital letter and your button was a submit type so it was trying to submit it to the server.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Daily Calorie Goal</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function Calculate() {

        var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var goal = document.getElementById("goal").value;

        if(gender=="male") 
            {
                val1 = 6.23 * weight;
                val2 = 12.7 * height;
                val3 = 6.8 * age;
                dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

                result = 66 + val1 + val2 - val3;

                cals = result * 1.55;
                calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;

            }
        else if (gender=="female")
            {
                val1 = 6.23 * weight;
                val2 = 4.7 * height;
                val3 = 4.7 * age;
                dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

                result = 655 + val1 + val2 - val3;

                cals = result * 1.55;
                calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;
            }



        document.write ('This is your Daily Calorie Goal. To achieve your goal, just consume fewer than this number of calories every day:<b>   ' + calMax.toFixed(2) + '</b><br>');

    }



    </script>

    <form action="#">
        Gender  : <select id="gender"><option value="male">Male</option><option value="female">Female</option></select><br />
        Weight (lbs.)   : <input type="text" id="weight" /><br />
        Height (inches): <input type="text" id="height" /><br />
        Age     : <input type="text" id="age" /><br />
        Goal    : <select id="goal"><option value=5>Lose 5 Pounds</option><option value=10>Lose 10 Pounds</option><option value=15>Lose 15 Pounds</option><option value=20>Lose 20 Pounds</option><option value=25>Lose 25 Pounds</option></select><br />


        </fieldset>
        <input type="button" value="Get My Daily Calorie Goal" onclick="Calculate()" />
    </form>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the screen is a side-effect of `document.write`. What you probably want is having an element that will contain the text.

After the form element, you can append an holder element:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

You can then set the content of it:

```
document.getElementById("result").textContent = "This is your daily...";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just got to change this right here:

```
var goal = document.getElementById("goal").value;
```

to this

```
var goal = document.getElementById("Goal").value;
```